# Getting more information about ELF file

Tags: linux, elf

I started to explore and read about the ELF file in Linux and I don't understand how I can get more information about the headers of the file.
Did someone has a code or something that can print what i need it will make this subject more clear!

Comment: Is [`readelf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) not good enough?

Comment: Hello John,we have exactly what you are looking for....

Comment: Well, as this is one of the core tools for *elf*, I'd assume you'd find it when you're *reading about ELF* ;)

Answer (score 2):

*The* tool for examining ELF files is [readelf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html).

On Linux, `eu-readelf` (part of [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/)) often provides even better information.

Comment: The `elfutils` source code is also easier to understand binutils with its BFD abstraction.